# Randomize enum from references

Tags: c#, object, random

Trying to randomize enum values. Problem is the enumerations are in a references file that I refer to in my code. For example

```
        public enum AccountTypeEnum
{
        Direct,
        Partner,
        Referral,
        Resold,
}
```

is in my reference file and in my code I need to refer to AccountTypeEnum and randomize it so when I run my program I can get one of those 4 values.

What I have so far that I believe randomizes the values is this:

```
   public void AcctType()
        {
            string[] Types = Enum.GetNames(typeof(AccountTypeEnum));            
            Random randType = new Random();
            int randomenum = randType.Next(Types.Length);
            var ret = Enum.Parse(typeof(AccountTypeEnum), Types[randomenum]);
        }
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. created a new class:

```
public class EnumRandomizeer
{
    public static Random rand = new Random();
    public static T GetRandomValue<T>()
    {
        T[] values = (T[])(Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)));
        return values[rand.Next(0, values.Length)];
    }
}
```

And when referencing the enum value I refered to the class like this:

```
 AccountTypeEnum randomAcct = EnumRandomizeer.GetRandomValue<AccountTypeEnum>();
```

Worked great!

Comment: maybe also a check to see if `T` is an enum: `if(!typeof(T).IsEnum) { throw... }`